# Python argparse value range help message appearance

Tags: python, range, argparse

I have an argument for a program that is an integer from 1-100 and I just don't like the way that it shows up in the -h help message when using argparse (it literally lists 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,... etc)

Is there any way to change this or have it represented in another way?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the code for those who asked:

```
norse = parser.add_argument_group('Norse')
norse.add_argument('-n', '--norse', required=False, help='Run the Norse IPViking scan.', action='store_true')
norse.add_argument('--threshold', required=False, type=int, choices=range(0,101), help='Threshold (0-100) denoting at what threat level to provide additional data on an IP \
                        address. Default is 49.', default=49)
```

Comment: Can you post your code example?

Comment: API doesn't suggest anything, may be rather than using choices, you can implement your own check.

Comment: You could try looking at argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, I haven't used it myself, but it might provide the kind of customization you need.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about simply ditching the built in check and running my own, but it would be nice if I could keep it within the argparse... oh well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the [`metavar` parameter](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#metavar) of `add_argument()`.

For example:

```
norse = parser.add_argument_group('Norse')
norse.add_argument('-n', '--norse', required=False, help='Run the Norse IPViking scan.', action='store_true')
norse.add_argument('--threshold', required=False, type=int, choices=range(0,101),
                   metavar="[0-100]", 
                   help='Threshold (0-100) denoting at what threat level to provide additional data on an IP \
                        address. Default is 49.', default=49)
```

Test:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

norse = ArgumentParser()

norse.add_argument('-n', '--norse', required=False, help='Run the Norse IPViking scan.', action='store_true')
norse.add_argument('--threshold', required=False, type=int, choices=range(0,101), metavar="[0-100]", help='Threshold (0-100) denoting at what threat level to provide additional data on an IP address. Default is 49.', default=49)


norse.print_help()
```

Results

```
usage: -c [-h] [-n] [--threshold [0-100]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -n, --norse          Run the Norse IPViking scan.
  --threshold [0-100]  Threshold (0-100) denoting at what threat level to
                       provide additional data on an IP address. Default is
                       49.
```

Comment: `metavar` works for the `usage` and `help`.  It doesn't help with the error message.  More on this at http://bugs.python.org/issue16418 and http://bugs.python.org/issue16468

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the references. That's very interesting to know.

Answer (score 8):

You can customize action, e.g:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse


class Range(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, minimum=None, maximum=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.min = minimum
        self.max = maximum
        kwargs["metavar"] = "[%d-%d]" % (self.min, self.max)
        super(Range, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
        if not (self.min <= value <= self.max):
            msg = 'invalid choice: %r (choose from [%d-%d])' % \
                (value, self.min, self.max)
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, msg)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, value)


norse = argparse.ArgumentParser('Norse')
norse.add_argument('--threshold', required=False, type=int, min=0, max=100,
                   action=Range,
                   help='Threshold [%(min)d-%(max)d] denoting at what threat \
                         level to provide additional data on an IP address. \
                         Default is %(default)s.', default=49)
args = norse.parse_args()
print args
```

Test it:

```
~: user$ ./test.py --threshold 10
Namespace(threshold=10)
~: user$ ./test.py --threshold -1
usage: Norse [-h] [--threshold [0-100]]
Norse: error: argument --threshold: invalid choice: -1 (choose from [0-100])
~: user$ ./test.py -h
usage: Norse [-h] [--threshold [0-100]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  --threshold [0-100]  Threshold [0-100] denoting at what threat level to
                       provide additional data on an IP address. Default is
                       49.
```

Comment: I would customize the `type` rather than the `action`.

Answer (score 8):

With a custom `type`, it is easier to control the error message (via the `ArgumentTypeError`).  I still need the `metavar` to control the usage display.

```
import argparse

def range_type(astr, min=0, max=101):
    value = int(astr)
    if min<= value <= max:
        return value
    else:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('value not in range %s-%s'%(min,max))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
norse = parser.add_argument_group('Norse')
...
norse.add_argument('--range', type=range_type, 
    help='Value in range: Default is %(default)s.',
    default=49, metavar='[0-101]')
parser.print_help()
print parser.parse_args()
```

producing:

```
2244:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack25295487.py --ran 102
usage: stack25295487.py [-h] [-n] [--threshold [0:101]] [--range [0-101]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit

Norse:
  ...
  --range [0-101]      Value in range: Default is 49.
usage: stack25295487.py [-h] [-n] [--threshold [0:101]] [--range [0-101]]
stack25295487.py: error: argument --range: value not in range 0-101
```

I could use `functools.partial` to customize the range values:

```
type=partial(range_type, min=10, max=90)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple ways you can do it instead

```
def parseCommandArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', dest='myDest', choices=range(1,101), type=int, required=True, metavar='INT[1,100]', help='my help message')
    return parser.parse_args()
```

You can also use `action` instead, which I highly recommend since it allows more customization

```
def verify():
    class Validity(argparse.Action):
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            if values < 1 or values > 100:
                # do something
                pass
    return Validity

def parseCommandArgs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', dest='myDest', required=True, metavar='INT[1,100]', help='my help message', action=verify())
    return parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Thanks! 8 years later your metavar suggestion helped me with a similar problem where argparse was printing all ~65k port numbers in the help message.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library for this: [argparse-range](https://pypi.org/project/argparse-range/)

```py
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser
>>> from argparse_range import range_action
>>> parser = ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("rangedarg", action=range_action(0, 10), help="An argument")
>>> args = parser.parse_args(["0"])
>>> args.rangedarg
0
>>> parser.parse_args(["20"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
argparse.ArgumentTypeError: Invalid choice: 20 (must be in range 0..=10)
```

Helptext is added transparently:

```
foo.py --help

usage: foo.py [-h] rangedarg

positional arguments:
  rangedarg   An argument (must be in range 0..=10)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Other features include:

- Handles `default`, `metavar`, and `nargs` consistently with default argparse handling
- Type inference, with explicit overrides using the `type` argument

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.