# Command line with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

I'm developing a simple project with the purpose or learning Python, actually I have version 3.6 and I wanted to build a command line tool to generate password with specific criteria. So fare here is what I got:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-a", "-auto", help="auto mode", action="store_true")
group.add_argument("-m", "-manual", help="manual mode", action="store_true")
parser.parse_args()
```

the dead end is I have no idea how to limit a command, example `-l -lenght` to the reqisite of having `-m` another stop is, how do I define `-l` so that it can accept a value, for example `-l:8` to specify a password of 8 characters, I also want to put a range limit on `-l` values, example `-l:8-256` and finally, I dont understand the difference between `-` and `--` when defining the parameters.

I have already done all the part of generating passwords, just need a way to control its flow from outside so implementing parameters looked like a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the choices option.

`add_argument('--length', type=int, choices=range(8,257)`

This will only accept integer values between 8 and 256 (inclusive).

As for your second question, `-` indicates the shorthand for an option, which is common in most CLI tools, well `--` indicates the long hand. It is common practice is CLI tools to provide both a long and a short hand for options.

Comment: how do I bing a parameter to only be used with another paramenter, say for example I can specify -l only when it is run -m while in auto modo I cannot do that and will not accept the lenght value.

Comment: That is best done in post-processing, after you have parsed all the options.

Comment: To may knowledge you cannot do that with argparse, but that is a very easy `if` statement that can be done after your arguments have been parsed

Comment: @KeeganFerrett can I add `choices=range(8,257)` to my `group.add_argument()` statement?

Comment: @S.Redrum it should work with any argument added, provided the array (created by the range function) is of the right type

Comment: Note that your usage message will show all 240+ values if you use `choices` like this.

Comment: @chepner an easy way around this is to change the usage with the `metavar` option. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295487/python-argparse-value-range-help-message-appearance for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom type to check for valid values:

```
from argparse import ArgumentTypeError

def passwd_len(s):
    try:
        s = int(s)
    except ValueError:
        raise ArgumentTypeError("'%s' is not an integer" % (s,))

    if not (8 <= s <= 256):
        raise ArgumentTypeError("%d is not between 8 and 256, inclusive" % (s,))

    return s

parser.add_argument("--length", "-l", type=passwd_len)
```

---

The difference between `--` and `-` is one of conventions. Historically, options were single-letter arguments prefixed with a `-`, and groups of options could be combined: `-ab` was the same as `-a -b`. In order to 
support that convention *and* allow longer option names, a new convention
of using `--` to prefix multi-character names was devised. `--length` is a single option, not a group of six options `-l`, `-e`, `-n`, `-g`, `-t`, and `-h`. Long options cannot be grouped.

I would define the `-a` and `-m` options like this:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument("-a", "--auto", help="auto mode", action="store_const", const="auto", dest="mode")
group.add_argument("-m", "--manual", help="manual mode", action="store_const", const="manual", dest="mode")
group.add_argument("--mode", choices=["auto", "manual"])
```

Now instead of having two Boolean attributes that can never have the same value, you have just one attribute whose value you can check directly. Think of `--mode` as being the canonical way of choosing a mode, with `-a` and `-m` as shortcuts for selecting a specific mode.

Comment: what is the advantage of havind a third attribute named `--mode` respect using alternatively only `-a` or `-m`?

Comment: You could drop that option completely, and still have `-a` and `-m` as the only way to set the `mode` destination. I threw it in as sort of an afterthought. (You could think of it as demonstrating just how flexible you can be in setting a single destination.)